# why do i have to add a new variable in this code

Tags: c++

I was trying to write a code that takes two numbers as a input and change the numbers into words in certain rules.

Below is the code I wrote at first, but whatever input I put in, the loop starts from x=0.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    string nums[10] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

    int x,y;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;

    for (int x = x; x <= y; x++){
        if (x <= 9){
            cout << nums[x] << "\n";
        }
        else if (x % 2 == 0){
            cout << "even" << "\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "odd" <<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the second code I wrote and it worked as I wanted to.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    string nums[10] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

    int x,y;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;

    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++){
        if (i <= 9){
            cout << nums[i] << "\n";
        }
        else if (i % 2 == 0){
            cout << "even" << "\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "odd" <<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I found out that if I add a variable, it works as what I wanted too. I found the solution but I don't know why I have to add a variable and why the first one always starts from x=0.

Comment: Both times you define a new variable. But in the first code the new variable is also named `x` and "hides" the other `x` outside the `for` loop., That it starts at `0` is just by chance, `int x = x;` initializes it to whatever happens to be in the *uninitialized* `int x`.

Comment: You don't need another `x`. Try `for (; x <= y; x++){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first sample that you provided you  defined a local variable(x) as same name in outer block:

```
  for (int x = x; x <= y; x++)
```

In fact shadowing of variable take place here and c++ hide the declaration of variable of outer block with same name in nested block.